# Add tooltip, whose value is same as span value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If I have `<span>some text</span>`, how can I have this:

`<span title="*whatever is between span tags:* some text (in this case)">some text</span>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're building that HTML yourself, then just add the text into a title attribute at the time you're generating the html. e.g, in PHP it would be:

```
$text = 'some text';

<span title="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($text) ?>"><?php echo $text ?></span>
```

if you're doing it after the fact via Javascript, then (using jquery):

```
$('span').each(function () {
     this.attr('title', this.text());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("span[title]").each(function(){$(this).attr("title",$(this).text())});
```

That's how I'd do it.

http://jsfiddle.net/SYkEK/

Comment: Note that this will only work for `<span>` tags which already have a title attribute defined.

Comment: @T.Stone yup!  My example illustrates this.